# Using jax-rs to redirect get request and return response to solve CORS issue?

Tags: angularjs, rest, servlets, jax-rs, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to retrieve some data from webservice by using ajax request from angularjs application. I can't do it directly due to [CORS issue](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), for example you can see this question [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

As far as I know the only solution I have, is to perform request to 3rd party server from my server and then return it from my server to my client, it's illustrated by following scheme:
`client -> my server -> 3rd party server -> my server -> client`.

The straight forward solution is to use JAX-RS to communicate between my client and my server and [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library to communicate between my server and 3rd party server, but I doubt is there solution which based only on tools which JAX-RS provides me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm using JAX-RS 2.0 and it has its own client, so it was simple:

```
@GET
public Response getRedirectedRequest(@QueryParam("query") String query){

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://example.com")
                                    .path("/path/api/")
                                    .queryParam("q", query);

    Response response = target.request()
            .accept("application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .get();

    String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
    response.close();

    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```